# Exceptions with Ext JS 6.5.3 TreeStore implementation

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs6-classic, treestore

I have downloaded Ext JS 6.5.3 evaluation package and using it to evaluate migration in my project.

I tried migrating from Ext JS 4.2 to the latest version Ext JS 6.5.3. Due to nature of my existing project, currently I cannot use Sencha Cmd to build my application. I'm using a traditional way of including the required JS and CSS files in my project and running the application. I have successfully migrated all my codebase but getting the below exceptions with the `TreeMenu` implementation.

I have created a Sencha Fiddle to reproduce the issue https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2iac

I tried debugging further into `extjs-debug.js`, but couldn't get any clue about these exceptions. Exception that I'm getting

[image]

Comment: Read the first error in the console: "Ext.ComponentManager.register(): Duplicate component id "navTree""

Comment: @Evan : I think I got the issue. I have updated the fiddle, removed all the errors except the "Exception : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'parentNode' of null". This is mainly coming from the function call : tree.removeHeaderEle(); If I comment it, this exception goes away. I have to now think what can I do to achieve the same functionality as of this function.